# Jesus teaching about the Trinity

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, trinity

Are there any verses in the bible where Jesus is quoted teaching or supporting the trinity?

Comment: @DJClayworth I disagree.  I am specifically asking for what Jesus said about it, not what the bible says about it.  I'm looking for quotes.

Comment: The answer I referenced gives the biblical evidence for the Trinity. You can look at the passages which are quotes from Jesus for yourself, and decide which ones satisfy you.

Comment: Without defining what you mean by the 'idea of the Trinity' the question is open to many answers as you can see. Maybe your question should be, "Did Jesus understand the Greek philosophical concept of the trinity? Can this be seen in his teachings?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following Scriptures, Jesus speaks of the separation of persons of the Trinity:

John 5:30 through 32 KJV

> 30  I can of mine own self do nothing: as I hear, I judge: and my judgment is just; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of the Father which hath sent me.
>
> 31  If I bear witness of myself, my witness is not true.
>
> 32  There is another that beareth witness of me; and I know that the witness which he witnesseth of me is true.

John 17:21  KJV

> That they all may be one; as thou, Father, art in me, and I in thee, that they also may be one in us: that the world may believe that thou hast sent me.

There are a total of 15 places where Jesus spoke of the separation of the Father and the Son, and in the following Scripture Jesus is promising to send an entirely different Deity than those two:

John 14:16  KJV

> And I will pray the ***Father, and he shall give you another Comforter,*** that he may abide with you for ever;

and in the following Scripture he identifies that Deity as the Holy Spirit:

John 14:26  KJV

> But the ***Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost,*** whom the ***Father will send in my name,*** he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

This event prophesied by Jesus took place at Pentecost:

Acts 2:1 through 4    KJV

> 1  And when the day of Pentecost was fully come, they were all with one accord in one place.
>
> 2  And suddenly there came a sound from heaven as of a rushing mighty wind, and it filled all the house where they were sitting.
>
> 3  And there appeared unto them cloven tongues like as of fire, and it sat upon each of them.
>
> 4  And they were all filled with the Holy Ghost, and began to speak with other tongues, as the Spirit gave them utterance.

Comment: You've asserted that the Holy Spirit is deity without explaining it. In what way do these statements of Jesus assert the deity of the Holy Spirit? I think that's part of the question.

Comment: @ mojo First of all let's determine what Deity means: DEITY, n.1. Godhead; divinity; the nature and essence of the Supreme Being. 2. God; the Supreme Being, or infinite *self-existing Spirit.Genesis 1:2  KJV And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.Matthew 3:16-17  KJV And Jesus, when he was baptized, went up straightway out of the water: and, lo, the heavens were opened unto him, and he saw the Spirit of God descending like a dove, and lighting upon him .....:

Comment: @ mojo The Greek word for "another" in John 14:16 is allos which refers to another of the same kind, instead of heteros another of a different kind.

Comment: @CecilBeckum My point was that you did not attempt to validate this assertion in your answer. It's a decent answer, you just didn't answer this question I had when I read it, "Does Jesus say/imply that the Holy Spirit is deity?" You've defined deity, and you've mentioned the "Spirit of God" but you haven't connected the dots. Perhaps I'm just being dense, but  the implicit conclusions that you perhaps assume as obvious are not necessarily so obvious to me.

Comment: @Jason I occasionally hear word study arguments that fail to address the question, is there a way to say the other thing? Is there a word that means "another" that does not imply "same" or "different"? Would it have been meaningful to say heteros? What would the use of heteros implied? Does it necessarily mean fundamentally different in a way that cannot be God? In what sense is "of a different kind" impossible to apply to God? Forgive me, I am uneducated in these matters.

Comment: @ mojo maybe I'm the dense one, but when Jesus identified the Comforter as the Holy ghost in John 14:26 (which I went back and highlighted) Seemed to be as much identification of the Comforter as needed, and by showing in my comments that the Holy Spirit was present at Creation, would dispel any doubts you might have. I know of no Scriptures which designate either Jesus or God as Deity either, but have no doubt they are.

Answer (score 3):

In Matthew 28:19 (KJV) Jesus supports the doctrine of the Trinity: (why would He mention all Three individually if all Three were the same?)

> Go ye therefore, and teach all nations, baptizing them in the name of
>   the **Father**, and of the **Son**, and of the **Holy Ghost**:

If you have the time look at Bro. David Lamb's [*Plain & Obvious Proof Texts Through the New Testament*](http://davidlambministries.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=16&Itemid=24) concerning the Trinity.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: Nice answer.  I am not saying this site is right but you may find this interesting http://www.focus-search.com/shc/matt2819.html

Comment: It looks like their main point is that this verse is referring to one Person because the word "name" is singular. However, a more detailed look into the Greek text and the "Granville Sharp rule" seems to prove that this verse does indeed support the doctrine of the Trinity. See [this](http://www.velocity.net/~edju70/web/Trinity7.htm) for more information.